# Clear chart by click in highcharts

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I apologize for my English, I hope everything will be clear.

The question is: is it possible to make in highcharts so that when you click on the chart, the selection of all series is reset.

Now in more detail. I have graphs done using the R language package [rCharts](https://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/).

rCharts:

```
library(rCharts)

HideOtherSeriesOnClick <- function() {
  "#! function(event) {
   var selected = this.index;

   $.each(this.chart.series, function(index, series) {
      if (selected != index) {
         if (series.visible) {
            series.setVisible(false, false);
         } else {
            series.setVisible(true, false);
         }
      }
   });
   this.redraw();
   } !#"
}

HideMostSeriesByClickOnField <- function() {
  "#! function () {
   chart = this;
   var count_visibles = 0;

   $.each(chart.series, function(index, series) {
      if (series.visible) {
         count_visibles++;
      }
   });

   if (count_visibles < chart.series.length/2 ) {
      $(chart.series).each(function(){
         this.setVisible(true, false);
      });
      chart.redraw();
   } else {
      $(chart.series).each(function(){
         this.setVisible(false, false);
      });
      chart.redraw();
   }
}!#"
}

df <- data.frame(Wr.Hnd = c(18.5, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 4, 7, 5),
                 NW.Hnd = c(10, 12, 14, 9, 15, 12, 20, 23, 25),
                 Clap = rep(c("Right", "Left", "Center"), each = 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#data <- MASS::survey
h1 <- hPlot(x = "Wr.Hnd", y = "NW.Hnd", data = df, type = "line", group = "Clap")
h1$chart( events = list(click = HideMostSeriesByClickOnField()))
h1$plotOptions(series = list( events = list(click = HideOtherSeriesOnClick())))
h1
```

Charts:
[image]

Charts after one click on the plot:
[image]

Charts after click on "Left" in legend:
[image]

Now we are moving from rCharts to highcharter and we would like to keep this functionality. The problem is that these functions were written by another person, I do not know JS. Just copy-paste, of course, did not work. So my question is is it possible to implement something like this in highcharts and what should the code look like. Can be shown in pure JS in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/21971/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps I poorly explained, sorry. This question is not about rCharts, because on rCharts everything works, I just gave an example. I need the same functionality on highcharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your requirement but I forked your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8gzb5yd1/).

I added an event on the chart using this

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    events: {
        click: function () {
           for(let i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++){
                chart.series[i].hide();
           }
        }
    }
},
```

so basically on click, all the chart series are hidden one by one. I used highcharts' documentation if you need references.

Comment: No, it is a wrong answer, because it concerns Highcharts, not rChart.

Comment: @raf18seb "Now we are moving from rCharts to highcharter and we would like to keep this functionality." from my understanding the OP wants to know how to implement this in highchart and already has the rChart code. Also in the fiddle he has provided Highcharts code, to be enhanced.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov, Yes, that's what I asked. Thank you very much.